# gsoap segfaults my application (written in C) in every second time I call

Tags: c++, c, web-services, soap, struct

My gsoap Client Caller is getting segfaulted in every second call of `soap_call___ns4__QueryAccBalIO`. As per documentation of gsoap I'm allocating memory via soap_malloc and release it with soap_end and soap_free is also called after each cycle below is some of the piece of code I'm using in my Client Caller.

```
struct soap *soap = soap_new();

/**** Declaration of Client Structures ****/

struct _ns1__QUERYACCBAL_USCOREIOFS_USCOREREQ *QueryBal;
struct _ns1__QUERYACCBAL_USCOREIOFS_USCORERES *QueryRes;
struct _ns2__CREATETRANSACTION_USCOREIOPK_USCOREREQ *CreateTran;
struct _ns2__CREATETRANSACTION_USCOREIOPK_USCORERES *ResTran;
struct _ns2__REVERSETRANSACTION_USCOREIOPK_USCOREREQ *ReverseTran;
struct _ns2__REVERSETRANSACTION_USCOREIOPK_USCORERES *RevResTran;


if (!soap)
{
 printf ("Exiting Thread.......");
 return (void*) 0;
}


/**** Allocation ****/

QueryBal = (struct _ns1__QUERYACCBAL_USCOREIOFS_USCOREREQ *)soap_malloc(soap,sizeof(struct _ns1__QUERYACCBAL_USCOREIOFS_USCOREREQ));
QueryBal->FCUBS_USCOREHEADER=(struct ns1__FCUBS_USCOREHEADERType *)soap_malloc(soap,sizeof(struct ns1__FCUBS_USCOREHEADERType));
QueryBal->FCUBS_USCOREBODY.ACC_Balance=(struct ns1__Acc_Bal_Req_type *)soap_malloc(soap,sizeof(struct ns1__Acc_Bal_Req_type));
QueryRes = (struct _ns1__QUERYACCBAL_USCOREIOFS_USCORERES *)soap_malloc(soap,sizeof(struct _ns1__QUERYACCBAL_USCOREIOFS_USCORERES));

/**** Section of Assignment *****/

/**** Just right after Assignment Section gsoap Client Call ****/

rc = soap_call___ns4__QueryAccBalIO(soap,ReqResElements[a2->WS_ID].ConnectionString, NULL, QueryBal, QueryRes);

/**** Section Where soap_end() and soap_free() is being called *****/

if (rc)
{
    // SOAP REQUEST REJECTED :(

    printf("SOAP Request Rejected :( ");

        soap_end(soap);

    soap_free(soap);

    printf("Exiting Thread.....");

    return (void *) 0;

}

soap_end(soap);
soap_free(soap);
```

Now as per my understanding it should work fine, but when my client caller calls `soap_call___ns4__QueryAccBalIO` first time it gets successful result. But second time when my client caller calls same function it gets segfaulted.

When I remove soap_end(soap) and soap_free(soap) from my code then it does not segfault, But, by not calling soap_end and soap_free It may face memory leak issue.

Comment: `soap_end` and `soap_free` sound like calls that will invalidate the  pointer you created with `soap_new` at the beginning, and a segfault sounds like you're reusing that pointer after calling `soap_end`/`soap_free` on it.  Only call `soap_end`/`soap_free` when you're done with the object that `soap_new` created.

Comment: Dear Kyle, in each cycle whenever thread is invoked soap object is reinitialised with soap_new. soap_end and soap_free is only called there is no need of soap object .

Answer (score 0):

Surely a memory checker like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) will helps you.

What I feel strange in your code is why using soap_malloc to allocation request/response arguments.

Did you try :

```
_ns1__QUERYACCBAL_USCOREIOFS_USCOREREQ QueryBal;
QueryBal.FCUBS_USCOREHEADER=(struct ns1__FCUBS_USCOREHEADERType *)soap_malloc(soap,sizeof(struct ns1__FCUBS_USCOREHEADERType));
QueryBal.FCUBS_USCOREBODY.ACC_Balance=(struct ns1__Acc_Bal_Req_type *)soap_malloc(soap,sizeof(struct ns1__Acc_Bal_Req_type));
_ns1__QUERYACCBAL_USCOREIOFS_USCORERES QueryRes;
...
rc = soap_call___ns4__QueryAccBalIO(soap,ReqResElements[a2->WS_ID].ConnectionString, NULL, &QueryBal, &QueryRes);
```